# How to fix a cell that has tunnels?

Tags: prison-architect

How can I fix a cell with tunnels or holes? I tried destroy the wall and rebuild it without success. Any hints?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Remove Tunnels option is found in the Materials menu. Select it and drag it over the tunnel and your workers will remove it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing the Xbox One Version then this is found under Demolition.

Comment: This should really be a comment on or edit to the accepted answer.