# On Ps4 prison architect how do I remove the tunnels

Tags: ps4, prison-architect

I can not remove the tunnels on PS4, so can anyone help me?

Comment: [Potentially relevant](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166662/how-to-fix-a-cell-that-has-tunnels?rq=1) but I know the console version has a different UI. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://forums.double11.com/t/can-not-find-the-option-to-fill-in-tunnels-in-the-ps4-version/905/2),

> You push left on the d-pad to bring up the menu for building stuff and then it's under demolition